# Disabled specific date range

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm using [Betterpickers](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) for Calendar date-picker. I need to disable certain dates (coming from API). I tried to disable some dates but my code didn't disabled those dates. The only disabled dates are those which are outside the set date range i.e. minDate and maxDate. Is these some issue with my code?

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment.OnDateSetListener{

   Button dateBtn;
   private static final String FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER = "fragment_date_picker_name";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dateBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dateBtn);
        dateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // For Calendar range
                DateTime now = DateTime.now();


                MonthAdapter.CalendarDay minDate = new MonthAdapter.CalendarDay(now.getYear(), now.getMonthOfYear()-1, now.getDayOfMonth());
                MonthAdapter.CalendarDay maxDate = new MonthAdapter.CalendarDay(now.getYear()+1, now.getMonthOfYear(), now.getDayOfMonth());

                Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                startCal.setTimeInMillis(minDate.getDateInMillis());
                Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                endCal.setTimeInMillis(maxDate.getDateInMillis());


                SparseArray<MonthAdapter.CalendarDay> disabledDays = new SparseArray<>();

                // For diable date range
                String startdateTime = "2017/03/12";
                String enddateTime = "2017/03/30";
                DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

                DateTime startJodaDate = dtf.parseDateTime(startdateTime);
                DateTime endJodaDate = dtf.parseDateTime(enddateTime);

                MonthAdapter.CalendarDay minDisableDate = new MonthAdapter.CalendarDay(startJodaDate.getYear(), startJodaDate.getMonthOfYear(), startJodaDate.getDayOfMonth());
                MonthAdapter.CalendarDay maxDisableDate = new MonthAdapter.CalendarDay(endJodaDate.getYear(), endJodaDate.getMonthOfYear(), endJodaDate.getDayOfMonth());

                Calendar startDisableCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                startDisableCal.setTimeInMillis(minDisableDate.getDateInMillis());

                Calendar endDisableCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                startDisableCal.setTimeInMillis(maxDisableDate.getDateInMillis());

                while (startDisableCal.before(endDisableCal)) {

                    int key = Utils.formatDisabledDayForKey(startDisableCal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            startDisableCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), startDisableCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    disabledDays.put(key, new MonthAdapter.CalendarDay(startDisableCal));

                    startDisableCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                }





                CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment cdp = new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment()
                        .setDateRange(minDate, maxDate)
                        // Set Disabled Days
                        .setDisabledDays(disabledDays)
                        .setOnDateSetListener(MainActivity.this);

                cdp.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        int correctMonth = monthOfYear+1;
        System.out.println("sammy_DATE: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+correctMonth+"/"+year);
    }
}
```

Comment: At least give a reason to down vote even if you are not answering query.

Answer (score 2):

I got it all worked out. I just needed to give the correct month in the CalendarDay. As the month in BetterPickers starts from 0(zero) and we usually starts from 1(one), I just needed to subtract 1 from both `minDisableDate` and `maxDisableDate.

```html
MonthAdapter.CalendarDay minDisableDate = new MonthAdapter.CalendarDay(startJodaDate.getYear(), startJodaDate.getMonthOfYear()-1, startJodaDate.getDayOfMonth());
MonthAdapter.CalendarDay maxDisableDate = new MonthAdapter.CalendarDay(endJodaDate.getYear(), endJodaDate.getMonthOfYear()-1, endJodaDate.getDayOfMonth());
```